# Return Best Match From Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In an array of objects:

```js
const candidates = [
   {
     "id": "a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-65821d50a0b5",
     "name": "alpha",
     "skills": [
        "Go",
        "Ruby",
        "Python" 
     ]
  },
 {
     "id": "a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-6554880a0b5",
     "name": "metta",
     "skills": [
        "Express",
        "Ruby",
        "Python",
        "swift"
     ]
  },
  {
     "id": "a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-65821d50a0b5",
     "name": "Thitha",
     "skills": [
        "Javascript",
        "React",
        "Express",
        "Node"
     ]
  },
]
```

I want to write a function that when I pass in a number of skill set as an array i.e `["Javascript", "Express", "Node"]` I return the candidate who matches my skill set in this case it would be the last one  `Thitha`. I want to implement this function in a `req.query` endpoint of my API. Please Help.

The returned result would be:-

```js
{
     "id": "a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-65821d50a0b5",
     "name": "Thitha",
     "skills": [
        "Javascript",
        "React",
        "Express",
        "Node"
     ]
  }
```

**What I have tried so far:-**

```js
function getCandidate(subSet, set){
   const filtered = Object.values(set).filter(key => 
    subSet.includes(key)).reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = set[key]
    return obj
 }, {})
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of how subset object and set object look like

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: The title says "best match". What if the skill set cannot be matched exactly? For example, what happens when you want to find 3 skills, but all candidates match only two out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to `filter` array where `every` items of array exists:

```
let filters = ["Javascript", "Express", "Node"];
const result = candidates.filter(f => filters.every(e=> f.skills.some(s => s == e)));
```

So an example:

```js
const candidates = [
   {
     "id": "a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-65821d50a0b5",
     "name": "alpha",
     "skills": [
        "Go",
        "Ruby",
        "Python"
     ]
  },
 {
     "id": "a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-6554880a0b5",
     "name": "metta",
     "skills": [
        "Express",
        "Ruby",
        "Python",
        "swift"
     ]
  },
  {
     "id": "a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-65821d50a0b5",
     "name": "Thitha",
     "skills": [
        "Javascript",
        "React",
        "Express",
        "Node"
     ]
  },
];

let filters = ["Javascript", "Express", "Node"];
const result = candidates.filter(f => filters.every(e=> f.skills.some(s => s == e)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a combination of `filter`, `includes` and `every`:

```
function getCandidate(subSet, set) {
    return set.filter((candidate) => 
        subSet.every((skill) => candidate.skills.includes(skill))
    );
}
```

So what it does is filters the set (candidates) for such elements, which has at least all the skills listed in the subset.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `.filter()` directly on your `candidates` array rather than using `Object.values()` on it. For each object in this array, you can decide to keep it if `.every()` element in your `subset` is included (`.includes()`) in the object's `skill` array. You can then `.map()` the objects to their associated `name` values like so:

```js
const candidates = [{id:"a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-65821d50a0b5",name:"alpha",skills:["Go","Ruby","Python"]},{id:"a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-6554880a0b5",name:"metta",skills:["Express","Ruby","Python","swift"]},{id:"a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-65821d50a0b5",name:"Thitha",skills:["Javascript","React","Express","Node"]}];

const arr = ["Javascript", "Express", "Node"];
const getCandidate = (subSet, set) =>
  set.filter(
    ({skills}) => subSet.every(x => skills.includes(x))
  ).map(({name}) => name);

console.log(getCandidate(arr, candidates));
```

The above code assumes that there can be more than one person who has all the skills which appear in the subset array. If this is not the case (or you just want the first person) you can use `.find()` instead of `.filter()`:

```js
const candidates = [{id:"a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-65821d50a0b5",name:"alpha",skills:["Go","Ruby","Python"]},{id:"a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-6554880a0b5",name:"metta",skills:["Express","Ruby","Python","swift"]},{id:"a4b7d559-8437-4bec-a6d3-65821d50a0b5",name:"Thitha",skills:["Javascript","React","Express","Node"]}];

const arr = ["Javascript", "Express", "Node"];
const getCandidate = (subSet, set) =>
  (set.find(({skills}) => subSet.every(x => skills.includes(x))) || {}).name;

console.log(getCandidate(arr, candidates));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
Filter and sort results based on the number of skills matched

```
const getCandidate = (subSet, data) => {
    return data.filter(item => {
        let hasSkills = 0;
        item.skills.forEach(skill => {
            if(subSet.includes(skill)) {
                hasSkills++;
                item.hasSkills = hasSkills;
           }
        })
        return hasSkills > 0;
    }).sort((a, b) => {
        if(a.hasSkills > b.hasSkills) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a.hasSkills < b.hasSkills) {
        return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    })
}
```